# How to DIY a tent footprint for the 'Big Agnes Copper Spur UL2' tent?

Tags: tents, diy, tarp-tents, tent-footprints

Numerous customers who bought the [manufacturer-made tent footprint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AL61F6) for the ['Big Agnes Copper Spur UL2' tent](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GSYHOKG) reported on Amazon that the tent footprint is poorly made and NOT AT ALL a good purchase. 
The footprint is highly useful [to convert the tent into a tarp-tent](https://youtu.be/klXBi3rnbhM?t=3m30s) among other things.

I'm not sure what alternative footprint products are available to buy from the market (with the possibility of slightly altering it a bit myself to make it suit the tent). But if not possible, I'm considering making one myself. How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed instructions at [gizmodo.com/how-to-make-your-own-tent-footprint](http://gizmodo.com/how-to-make-your-own-tent-footprint-for-25-1666007412). The example used is even a Big Agnes (but one with an isosceles trapezoid rather than your simple rectangle).

Essentially, you measure your tent base, cut some Tyvek slightly larger so you can have strong folded edges, place grommets in each of the corners where the poles will go, and tie loops of nylon cord through each grommet for securing to the stakes when pitching.